# Showing that $\mathbb{C}^n = E_1 \bigoplus E_{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra

This problem is for a linear algebra class I am in, so I would prefer someone to point me in the right direction on this one. Anyway here is the problem:

Let $A \in M_n(\mathbb{C}^n)$ such that $A^2=I_n$. Let $E_{\lambda} = \{x \in M_n(\mathbb{C}^n): Ax =\lambda x\}$ Show that $\mathbb{C}^n = E_1 \bigoplus E_{-1}$ and thus show there exists an invertible matrix $S$ such that $S^{-1}AS = 
\begin{bmatrix}
I_r & 0 \\
0 & -I_{n-r} \\
\end{bmatrix}$.

So I have what I believe to be a proof which goes like this:

Since $A$ is nilpotent with $n=2$ it's not hard to show that this means that $A$ is diagonalizable and hence $dim(E_1) + dim(E_{-1}) = n$ and so since eigen vectors are linearly independent we have that $E_1 + E_{-1}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{C}^n$ and since $E_1 \cap E_{-1} = \emptyset$ we get the result that $\mathbb{C}^n = E_1 \bigoplus E_{-1}$.

The problem is that we haven't learned the fact that I used that a matrix $A$ is diagonalizable if and only if the sum of the dimensions of the eigen spaces is $n$.
So my question is what would be another approach to take to prove something like this if I am not able to use that fact. Also I would appreciate if someone could verify if my proof is correct if I was aloud  to use the fact. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nilpotent means $A^n$ is the zero matrix for some $n$.

Comment: Ah yes that is correct that's a dumb mistake. It wouldn't happen to be the case that a matrix such that $A^2 = I_n$ is also diagonalizable would it?

Comment: Did you learn about the Jordan normal form?

Comment: No we haven't learned that yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By assumption $0 = A^2 - I_n = (A+I_n)(A-I_n)$. This implies $\text{im}(A-I_n) \subseteq \ker(A+I_n)$. By the dimension formula we get $$n = \dim(\text{im}(A-I_n)) + \dim(\ker(A-I_n)) \leq \dim(\ker(A+I_n)) + \dim(\ker(A-I_n)) = \dim(E_{-1}) + \dim(E_1).$$
As $E_{-1} \cap E_1 = \{0\}$, this implies $\mathbb{C}^n = E_{-1} \oplus E_1$. Now you just plug in $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors into a matrix and this gives you $S$ (this is in fact just the proof that a matrix is diagonalizable if the sum of the dimensions of the eigenspaces is $n$, though).